# AFNetworkingを用いてphpにPOST送信をしたが、 json_decodeの値がNULLになる。

Tags: php, objective-c, json

iOSから2個の文字列をデータベース(MySQL)に保存したいと思っておりまして、
AFNetworkingを使って、JSON形式でphpにPOST送信するプログラムをテスト中です。
今回は以下のJSONデータをiOSからphpに送りたいと考えています。

・JSON

```
{
  “name” : “yamada”,
  “content” : “hello”
}
```

・iOSプログラム

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"name":@"yamada",
                         @"content":@"hello"};

NSString *url = @"http://kokun.sakura.ne.jp/test/test.php";
[manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseStr);
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

・phpプログラム

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$postDecode = json_decode($post);

// テキストファイルにログを出力
ob_start();
var_dump($postDecode);
$result =ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$fp = fopen("./dump.txt", "a+" );
fputs($fp, $result);
fclose( $fp );

?>
```

php側で受け取ったデータ(変数$post)を表示してみると

**string(25) "content=hello&name=yamada"**

という文字列が表示され、一見成功しているように思いましたが、
これをjson_decodeしてみた値(変数$postDecode)を表示してみると
値がNULLになってしまいます。
詳しい方、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

【追記】
アドバイスをいただけたおかげで、
下記コードで無事解決しました。

・phpプログラム(修正後)

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];　　　　// yamadaが表示される
$content = $_POST['content']; // helloが表示される。

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル選択を含まないフォームのPOSTは JSON ではなく、 application/x-www-form-urlencoded という形式を使うことが一般的です。

[パーセントエンコーディング - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0#application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded)

今回の場合もこの形式で送信されているように見えます。

PHPの場合、これは自動的にデコードされて `$_POST` に入っています。連想配列になっているので、 `$_POST['content']` といった形でもアクセスできます。

もし JSON 形式で送りたいということでしたら、 AFJSONRequestSerializer を使うとできそうです。

[ド定番OSS！AFNetworking 2.xの使い方 ｜ Developers.IO](http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/iphone/ios-afnetworking2/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。$_POST['name']と、$_POST['content']を見たところ、正確に表示されていました。
AFJSONRequestSerializerも検討してみます。